# background image size for Androidd

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'll make a picture for the Android background. But I need the size. some pictures are small, the resolution is distorted. What should be the background image size for Android? or do you have a site?

Answer (score 0):

Creates an image with the corresponding resolution then put it in particular folder like xxxhdpi,xxhdpi,xhdpi,hdpi...

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this should (hopefully) help:

- xxxhdpi: 1280px by 1920px
- xxhdpi: 960px by 1600px
- xhdpi: 640px by 960px
- hdpi: 480px by 800px
- mdpi: 320px by 480px
- ldpi: 240px by 320px